# OleDbConnection.State issue with Microsoft Access

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb, oledbconnection

I have a C# application that reads/writes from/to an Access Database.  I do this using an OleDbConnection.

Before a read / write, I want to check that my database connection is open.  It should be straight-forward....

```
if (Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open) Connection.Open();
```

While this generally works well, it is not working for situations where network access is interrupted.  The Connection.State is still recorded as 'Open', so I'd get an exception.  So, I tried this:

```
Connection.ResetState();
if (Connection.ConnectionState(DatabaseType) != ConnectionState.Open) Connection.Open();
```

Nope... That's not working either, as the ResetState() method isn't actually resetting the state.

So I tried this extension method (a bit ugly...)

```
public static ConnectionState ConnectionState(this OleDbConnection connection, DatabaseType type)
{
    connection.ResetState();
    if (type == DatabaseType.Access)
    {
        //Reset state might not work... Check that the datasource is locatable
        if (!File.Exists(connection.DataSource)) return System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed;
        return connection.State;
    }
    return connection.State;
}
```

This "sort of" works, in that it correctly identifies that the DataSource can't be located.  But then I get an exception when I try to open the database; not that it can't be found, but that its an invalid operation trying to open a connection that is already open!

I've spent about an hour trying to google to find a reliable way to get the true status of the database connection.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: How long do you keep your `OleDbConnection` objects around for? Personally I have short-lived instances that are created and disposed of within the scope of a single "user action" - so my code that creates them has a simple `while` loop (with timeout!) to ensure it's in the `Open` state.

Comment: I keep the objects around for a long time (but frequently open & close the connections).  I guess I could always Close() the connection then re-open it before each transaction => I found that OleDbConnection will simply let me 'Close' a connection that is broken anyway (and then I get a datasource not found exception trying to re-open it).

Answer (score 0):

Correct way to use `DbConnection` is to create a new one for every command. Connection pooling means there is not usually a big overhead, and any network issues in between are sorted out automatically.

Make sure to `Dispose` correctly.

Comment: It's a bit difficult to retrofit that into my application.  I have a set of base classes that take an OleDbConnection in the constructor, and I re-use that.  So I'm really looking for a way of reliably checking the connection state.